# Metapost : bypass errors mpost multi fig

Tags: metapost, export, bash

I'm working on a multi fig Metapost file. I'm wondering if it is possible to bypass the error message during running `mpost` and correctly export the other fig if there is a error in one of them ?

```
beginfig(1)
     draw (0,0)--(10,10);
endfig;

% error in fig 2
beginfig(2)
    draw (,10)-10,20);
endfig;

beginfig(3)
    draw (0,20)--(10,30);
endfig;
end.
```

I'm running the `mpost` command within a bash file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for (( ; ; ))
do
    # mpost
    mpost metapost.mp

    # wait 60 seconds
    sleep 60
done
```

Can I solve this with the bash program or directly in the Metapost file ?

Comment: An error might leave Metapost in an unstable state when starting the next figure, so the output could be unpredictable. Anyway, you're looking for `mpost -interaction=batchmode <filename>`

Comment: Super! I didn't know about the `-interaction=batchmode`. I was using a bash solution `echo -ne '\n' | mpost metapost.mp` but the batchmode looks better. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get in the end might not be usable, because errors in a figure may affect the following ones. However, there's a way for calling Metapost without it stopping at errors asking for input:

```
mpost -interaction=batchmode metapost.mp
```

is what you're looking for. No output on the terminal, just to the log file. In case of errors the exit code will be positive.